# How to get the id of Updatepanel which initiated a postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

Hi I need to intercept server callback after udate panel async post back and determine which panel initiated the request. The code is pretty simple:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(InterceptUpdateCallback);

function InterceptUpdateCallback(sender, args)
{
    var updatedPanels = args.get_panelsUpdated();    
    for (idx = 0; idx < updatedPanels.length; idx++) {
        if (updatedPanels[idx].id == "myUpdatePanel") {            
            StartSmth();
            break;
        }
      }
}
```

And it works when UpdatePanel is not inside another UpdatePanel. But when it is inside another UpdatePanel updatedPanels[idx].id has parent Updatepanel id. So how can I get the id of UpdatePanel which initiated the request (the inner UpdatePanel)? Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function InterceptUpdateCallback(sender, args) {
 if (sender._postBackSettings)
    alert(sender._postBackSettings.panelID);
 else
    alert('first load');    
}
```

**Update:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">
    protected void LinkButtons_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LabelMain.Text = LabelSub1.Text = LabelSub2.Text = LabelSub3.Text = string.Format("{0} Updated By {1}", DateTime.Now, ((Control)sender).ID);
    }
</script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-family: Tahoma;}
        fieldset { padding: 15px; }
        fieldset a 
        {
            float: right;
            clear: none;
            display: block;
            margin: 10px;
        }
        fieldset span
        {
            display: block;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function pageLoaded(sender, args) {
            if (sender._postBackSettings) {
                var panelId = sender._postBackSettings.panelID.split('|')[0];
                if (panelId == sender._scriptManagerID) {
                    var updatedPanels = args.get_panelsUpdated();
                    var affectedPanels = "Affected Panels:\n";
                    for(var x=0;x<updatedPanels.length;x++)
                        affectedPanels+= updatedPanels[x].id + "\n";
                    alert("Request initiated by ScriptManager\n\nMight be an async trigger, or child of an update panel with children as triggers set to false.\n\n"+affectedPanels);
                }
                else
                    alert("Request initiated by: " + panelId);
            }
        }
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoaded);
    </script>

    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateMain" runat="server" Text="UpdateMain" OnClick="LinkButtons_Click"></asp:LinkButton>,
    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateSub1" runat="server" Text="UpdateSub1" OnClick="LinkButtons_Click"></asp:LinkButton>,
    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateSub2" runat="server" Text="UpdateSub2" OnClick="LinkButtons_Click"></asp:LinkButton>,
    <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateSub3" runat="server" Text="UpdateSub3" OnClick="LinkButtons_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Main" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <fieldset>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" Text="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButtons_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                <legend>Main -  Update Mode:Conditional, Children As Triggers:False</legend>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelMain" runat="server" Text="LabelMain"></asp:Label>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Sub1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <fieldset>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="LinkButton2" OnClick="LinkButtons_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                            <legend>Sub1 - Update Mode:Always, Children As Triggers:True</legend>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelSub1" runat="server" Text="LabelSub1"></asp:Label>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Sub2" runat="server"  UpdateMode="Always" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" Text="LinkButton3" OnClick="LinkButtons_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                                        <legend>Sub2 - Update Mode:Always, Children As Triggers:True</legend>
                                        <asp:Label ID="LabelSub2" runat="server" Text="LabelSub2"></asp:Label>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateSub2" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>                            
                        </fieldset>                        
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateSub1" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="Sub3" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>

                        <fieldset>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" Text="LinkButton4" OnClick="LinkButtons_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
                            <legend>Sub3 - Update Mode:Conditional, Children As Triggers:False</legend>
                            <asp:Label ID="LabelSub3" runat="server" Text="LabelSub3"></asp:Label>
                        </fieldset>                        
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateSub3" />
                    </Triggers>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </fieldset>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateMain" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I doubt it will work since _postBackSettings is an internal property so you can't call it from your code directly.

Comment: this is javascript !! and it will give you the update panel id and the firing element id like this "UpdatePanel1|Button1".

Did you try it ?!

Comment: Yes I tried and error occurs since sender._postBackSettings is not avaliable

Comment: This is why I put a condition, when sender._postBackSettings == null it means the page was loaded (no postback, i.e: "first load"). It is filled when an update panel initiates a request.

Answer (score 0):

I will have a guess at this one.

Does setting `UpdateMode = Conditional` on the outer (or both) `UpdatePanel`s help? I think the problem is that you only get the "outermost" updated panel and if you do not set `UpdateMode` to `Conditional` the outer Panel is updated as well (even if you click something in the inner panel; see second reference).

For reference see

> Note that, if I remove the property
> UpdateMode=Conditional for the
> UpdatePanel1 (parent), both the labels
> will get refreshed.

from [ASP.NET 2.0 AJAX Extensions Update Panel - Nested Update Panel](https://web.archive.org/web/20200811165908/http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2007/05/16/112525.aspx)

and

> When set to Always, the UpdatePanel is
> updated on every postback raised from
> anywhere in the page, so from controls
> inside the panel, inside other panels
> or just on the page.

from [Remember to set UpdatePanel's UpdateMode to Conditional](https://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2007/05/24/updatemode-default-value-for-the-updatepanel-is-always.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to solution: the problem was that I had trigger control (Button) for child UpdatePanel which actually was outside this Update panel and inside parent UpdatePanel (sorry I hadn't noticed that). If you put Button inside child UpdatePanel - everything works fine.

Comment: That doesn't help in my situation, where I need the trigger control outside the update panels, and registered as an async trigger through the ScriptManager. In that case `sender._postBackSettings.panelID` contains the IDs of the trigger and the _script manager_, not the update panels.