# How to get the id of Updatepanel which is about to start a postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I need to get the id of the panel that is about to start a postback, so I have a generic way to block ui on this panel.

So far I have this function:

```
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    $('#' + args.get_updatePanelsToUpdate()[0]).block({ message: null }); 
}
```

attached like this:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
```

this works pretty well to get the id if control that causes partial postback is inside update panel, but if it is outside (using a trigger), args.get_updatePanelsToUpdate() is always null

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902508/how-to-get-the-id-of-updatepanel-which-initiated-a-postback) answer, but it wont work forme because function is fired after partial postback is complete, I need it before..

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here's what I did:

created 2 functions to block (on partial postback begin) and unblock (on partial postback end):

```
    function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
          $('#' +sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate[0].ReplaceAll('$', '_')).block({ message: 'loading...' }); 
    }
    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {        
          $('#' + sender._postBackSettings.panelsToUpdate[0].ReplaceAll('$', '_')).unblock();
    }
```

Registered above functions on my page right after my script manager:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
    </script>
```

Some conditions:

- I'm using [jquery UI block plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos) but you should use what better fits your needs.
- You update panels should have ClientIDMode="AutoID" if your using .NET 4.0 +
- I used the following helper function cause js doesn't make a real replace all and to deal with asp net autoID's:

  String.prototype.ReplaceAll = function (stringToFind, stringToReplace) {
      var temp = this;
      var index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
      while (index != -1) {
          temp = temp.replace(stringToFind, stringToReplace);
          index = temp.indexOf(stringToFind);
      }
      return temp;
  }

Comment: `.replace(/\$/g,'_')`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable (or animate in some other way) the UpdatePanel, why not just use [UpdatePanelAnimation](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/UpdatePanelAnimation/UpdatePanelAnimation.aspx)?  It provides you with the following hooks (not sure if that's the right word):

> **OnUpdating** - Generic animation played as when any UpdatePanel begins
>   updating
>   **OnUpdated** - Generic animation played after the UpdatePanel
>   has finished updating (but only if the UpdatePanel was changed)

Comment: thank you, but I want to do it as a general thing, I have a general js file on my master page so I thought on intercepting every partial postback with a single function, plus I hate ajax control toolkit

Comment: @Milox: Although hate is a strong word, I also prefer other approaches to adding dynamic functionality to pages.  That said, you're already using UpdatePanel (which I think is pretty evil).  At least UpdatePanelAnimation is a more or less standard approach which will most likely be documented better than whatever you write.  Is not using UpdatePanels at all an option or are you pretty heavily invested in them?

Comment: you're right, my apologies for that word, is just I've had such a bad experience with it, is to heavy and complex to use... I'm using update panels because is the easiest and more logical way to avoid full page refresh when you're under asp .net. UpdatePanelAnimation would work but I'll have to add one in every page I'm using an update panel and that's what I want to avoid